# Implementation of Go-routines vs Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, multithreading, go, task-parallel-library

I have just started learning Go. The strength of Go lies in goroutines for handling multiple concurrent connections. It was mentioned

> Goroutines can be considered as light-weight threads (but not actually threads) which can grow/shrink stack size and these are multiplexed into multiple os threads. Say if you have 1000 goroutines then these are scheduled to native OS threads based on blocking and waiting modes of goroutines.

Basically, I am from C# and Nodejs background. I am pretty confused how it is different from TaskParallelLibrary implemented in C#.

> TaskParallelLibrary hides the complexity of creating threads and managing them. You just start a task and CLR takes care of mapping them to native threads. Here you can create thousands of tiny tasks which are mapped and scheduled to OS threads. However TPL solves async problems specifically.

My question is how TPL is different from goroutines? Do goroutines use coroutines (pausable functions or?). TPL also multiplexes the async/syscalls operations to the thread pool, even Go also multiplexes syscalls to the thread pool.

Correct me if any of my assumptions are wrong. Could anyone help me where exactly the implementation differs? Why do goroutines claim to be faster than TPL?

Comment: Where do goroutines claim to be faster than TPL?

Comment: @Adrian I have already mentioned correct me if my assumptions are wrong. Sorry it was my assumption

Comment: The quoted paragraph about Go states that goroutines are more efficient than *threads*, which they are. I'm not aware of any official statement either way comparing goroutines to TPL.

Comment: @Adrian Do you think goroutines and TPL are one and the same?

Comment: No, goroutines are a feature of Go, TPL is a feature of C#, they are completely separate and distinct implementations of the same basic programming concept. I don't think anyone would claim they are the same thing, though some might claim they are roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chief difference is that Go runtime tightly couples scheduling of the goroutines with I/O which basically works like this: if a goroutine is about to block on some I/O operation or on a channel operation, the scheduler suspends that goroutine and re-activates it once it knows the original I/O or channel operation can now proceed. This allows writing Go code in purely sequential manner—without all the callback hell and "futures"/"promises" kludges, which merely wraps callbacks into objects, and also without `async`/`await` machinery which, again, merely couples compiler tricks with plain OS threads.

This stuff is very good explained in [this classic piece](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) by one of the developers of the Dart programming language.

Also see [this](https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler) and [this](https://rakyll.org/scheduler/).

Comment: On the other hand, `async`/`await` aren't tied to particular operations (you can even write your own awaitables if `Task` isn't the right abstraction) and if you're doing it right, you end up not tying up [any threads at all](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). At least as currently implemented in C#.

Comment: Yeah this sounds like async/await